How to parse JSON variables in Terraform?
I am importing a Terraform module, which outputs a variable as such, the value is in a string format, sample => "{domain: {subdomain: \"abc\"}}".
I'm trying to retrieve value key -> subdomain
# ....
output "some_values"{
    description = "{domain: {subdomain: \"abc\"}}"
    value = module.foo.bar
}

to read this , I declare a local as such
locals{
   inputs = jsondecode(module.main.some_values)
}

resource "some_resource" ".."{
    some_var = local.inputs["domain"]["subdomain"]
}

I get an error, module.main.som_values is object with 2 attributes.
any suggestions?

Where does the module.foo.var value come from?

@NickCaballero - it is from a different module , I exported/downloaded from a different project.

@suwa why do you think it's in JSON? Can you try with module.main.some_values.doman.subdomain?

Instead of:
some_var = local.inputs["domain"]["subdomain"]

Try:
some_var = local.inputs.domain.subdomain

Example
locals {
  json = "{ \"domain\": { \"subdomain\": \"abc\"} }"

  inputs = jsondecode(local.json)
}

output "subdomain" {
  value       = local.inputs.domain.subdomain
  description = "Value of subdomain"
}

Running terraform plan:
Changes to Outputs:
  + subdomain = "abc"

